# JavaScriptSerializer write string without quotes?

Tags: c#, .net, json, javascriptserializer

I am using `JavaScriptSerializer` concept to convert the object into json using custom `JavaScriptConverter`, and i met a problem, i need to write the string value of the property without qoutes.

Please help me to do this...

**Example**

```
{"dataSource":"ken.DataWidget(http://radixweb.com/DataSource.svc)","width":2000 }
```

In the above json i need to print the `ken.DataWidget(http://radixweb.com/DataSource.svc)` without qoutes

so i want json like below

```
{"dataSource":ken.DataWidget("http://radixweb.com/DataSource.svc"),"width":2000 }
```

Any help would be appreciable..

Answer (score 0):

[List of escape character](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available.aspx)

Your JSON is a String and when you want to have " in a string you must use one of the following:

```
string alias = "My alias is \"Tx3\"";
```